# Property is not found from properties file using @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, controller

I use properties file in spring framework

root-context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
<util:properties id="config" location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

java code

```
@Value("#{config[ebookUseYN]}")
String EBOOKUSEYN;
```

when Using url call(`@RequestMapping(value="/recommendbooks" , method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")`).. this work!

but, i use method call,

```
public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {

IndexManageController indexManage = new IndexManageController();
CommonSearchDTO commonSearchDTO = new CommonSearchDTO();

try {          
      if("Y".equals(EBOOKUSEYN)){
          indexManage.deleteLuceneDocEbook();
          indexManage.initialBatchEbook(null, commonSearchDTO);
      }
      indexManage.deleteLuceneDoc(); <= this point
      indexManage.deleteLuceneDocFacet();

      indexManage.initialBatch(null, commonSearchDTO);


     }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

when 'this point ' method call, changing controller, and don't read properties file field..

---

```
@Value("#{config[IndexBasePath]}")
    String IndexBasePath;

@RequestMapping(value="/deleteLuceneDoc" , method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody ResultCodeMessageDTO deleteLuceneDoc()
            throws Exception
{

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

ResultCodeMessageDTO result = new ResultCodeMessageDTO();
System.out.println(IndexBasePath);
}
```

It doesn't read `IndexBasePath`

Comment: Are you sure your properties file contains an `IndexBasePath` entry and it is right written in your code? Note that the entry name should be written as is since Spring will parse this case sensitive.

Comment: sure. 'IndexBasePath=D:\\BTBF_Index\\' entry is in properties file.. and other case use this entry.. but this case is not work..

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating a new instance of the `IndexManageController`, Spring doesn't know this instance and as such it will never be processed.

```
public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {

    IndexManageController indexManage = new IndexManageController();
```

Instead of creating a new instance inject the dependency for the `IndexManageController` so that it uses the pre-configured instance constructed and managed by Spring. (And remove the line which constructs a new instance of that class).

```
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private IndexManageController indexManage;

}
```

Your configuration is also loading the properties twice

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
<util:properties id="config" location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

Both load the config.properties file. Simply wire the config to the property-placeholder element.

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="config"/>
<util:properties id="config" location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

Saves you loading twice and saves you another bean.

Comment: how to inject the dependency for the IndexManageController ..????? spring so hard..

Comment: Add field, put `@Inject` (or `@Autowired` or `@Resource` on it) and done. Nothing hard about it.